# Order the items inside an array from nearest to fairest (from my position)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4

I created two functions to calculate the distance from me to a point on the map

```
func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)

        return from.distance(from: to)

    }


    func choSed(car:Car) {

        guard let coordinates = car.location  else {
            return
        }
        self.destination = coordinates


        if currentLocation != nil {
        let dis = distance(from: currentLocation!, to: coordinates)

        }
    }
```

and they work well. Now what i need to do (in another function) is to order the items inside an array `carsArray` from nearest to fairest (from my position)  . I don't know how can i do, maybe i have to calculate the distance of all the items of the array with a cycle and than use a filter to order the position of them, for now i tried to build something like this

```
for car in carsArray {
 for di in distance(from: currentLocation!, to: car.location!) {

               }
             }
```

but i get the error (Type 'CLLocationDistance' (aka 'Double') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence') and i also don't know if this could be the correct way to do it. Someone can help me?  (`car.location!` location in my custom class `Car` is `var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?` and the array `carsArray` is a vector of my custom class `Car` i can add to this class all the parameters that it could be useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLLocationDistance` is a typealias of a `Double`.

As already mentioned in one of  your previous questions the `in` parameter in a `for` loop must be an array or a range.

To order the items `sort` them

```
let sortedArray = carsArray.sorted { 
    distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $0.location!) < distance(from: currentLocation!, to: $1.location!) 
}
```

Comment: and if i know that a var x = distance(from me to x) how can i sort the array?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: i know the distance value from me to a x place and this value is represented from a variable x, so if i would like to sort the array not considering the start and the ending point but only the distance value how i can do?

Comment: The distance from what? The array contains locations (lat/lng points) and you got a distance. You need a distance from `car.location` to something to sort the array.